# Are AMP Pages faster than its Non-AMP version with no high-end features, plugins or related posts?

Tags: amp

For this question I have to surely show my site URL. My site has pages with no featured widgets, no related posts and no big-sized files to increase page size. Total requests are even less and site performs really better when it comes to YSlow and pagespeed scores. I use Cloudflare CDN with Knownhost dedicated server.

As such I feel that my sites pages are performing faster than the AMP version of it. So my question is, how can I know either AMP page or non-AMP version is performing better?